# Is there a way to conditionally check whether a WordPress post title is empty?

Tags: php, functions, theme-development

Inside a WordPress loop, I'd like to conditionally check to see if the post has a title, in order to provide necessary wrapping HTML. If the post does not have a title, I don't want any of the wrapping HTML to appear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While you're in The Loop you can check against the [WP_Post Object](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Post) like so:

```
<?php while( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

    <?php if( ! empty( $post->post_title ) ) : ?>

        <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>

    <?php endif; ?>

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Answer (score 4):

While checking `$post->post_title`, as in Howdy_McGee's answer, is probably safe in most cases, there may be some instances where a title is being modified by `the_title` filter. In that case, you have to get the title via the API to determine if it's really empty.

```
$title = trim( get_the_title() );

if( ! empty( $title ) ){
    echo 'there is a title';
} else {
    echo 'empty title';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add the before and after html tags to [the_title()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_title) function.
If the post_title is empty, nothing will be outputted.

```
the_title('<h1>', '</h1>');
```

Comment: Yes, but I'd like to add the_permalink() as well as other wrapping HTML inside, rather than a single opening and closing tag.

Answer (score 1):

To expand [@Milo](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/4771/milo)'s answer.

```
echo $title = ( ! empty( trim( get_the_title())) ? "there is a title" : "empty title";
```

or

```
echo $title = ( ! empty( trim( get_the_title())) ?: "empty title";
```